# How to save files in sdcard by accepting filename from user in android development

Tags: java, android

Hi i want to create different text file in sd card. the name to that file will be inputed by user. i have to read the filename and i have to create a file with that name in sd card.please anyone help me. thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your code and explain which part isn't working. I'm assuming you have made several attempts at trying to solve your problem before asking on here.

Comment: Can you please show us the code what you have tried to save the file into **sdcard** so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Get the file name using **EditText**.

```
EditText e1=findViewById(R.Id.editText1);
String filename=e1.getText();
File newFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory,filename);
```

Do write operation using this **newFile** object.

You need to have **Write External Storage** permission in manifest to write a file into sdcard.

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
</manifest>
```

To read a file from sdcard you need ** Read External Storage** permission.

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
</manifest>
```